# Gcov: Why are gcno files not created, but gcna are?

Tags: gcov

So I have in the past not had gcna files created because code didn't shutdown properly, but now sometimes I get the problem where I get the gnca files, but are missing the gnco files.  I have verified that everything is being compiled with --converage flag.  Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This was my mistake.  Turns out that while gnca files are created at runtime, the gnco files are created at compile time.  My makefile was inadvertently erasing these files before running tests, while it was trying to clean up gcov files with *.gc*, and not just *.gnca files.